# How to initialise cache for JUnit

Tags: java, caching, junit

I am writing some JUnits for a class I wrote. This class is responsible for ensuring a local cache gets built (a simple concurrent map cache). The call to build the cache is in the constructor;

```
public DBFactoryController(){
    buildCache();
    notifcation.startPushManager();
}
```

What happens in my test class is I create an instance variable of DBFactoryController

```
private DBFactoryController controller = new DBFactoryController();
```

However from what I have read, a new instance of the test class is generated for every test case, this means my cache gets rebuilt for every test which is slowing my tests down.

Is there a way i can structure this so that my cache would only be built once?

Thanks

Comment: If your controller is stateless then you can create it as a static field in the test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest may be to create a static instance of your DBFactoryController:

```
class DBFactoryController {
   private static DBFactoryController instance = null;
   public DBFactoryController getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new DBFactoryController();
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public DBFactoryController() {
      buildCache();
      notifcation.startPushManager();
   }
}
```

Then you can initialize the DBFactoryController instance in your test case like this:

```
private DBFactoryController controller = DBFactoryController.getInstance();
```

There are probably more elegant solutions using JUnit mechanisms, but this I guess is the simplest.